# Вводное отделяется запятой в присоединительной конструкции, если последняя сама отделяется с помощью тире?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Но в конце концов я это устроила, и едва я ее вновь увидела - в центре реабилитации в Дувре, - все, что нас разделяло, не то чтобы исчезло, но стало куда менее важным, чем другое - например, то, что мы вместе выросли в Хейлшеме, то, что мы знали и помнили такое, чего не знал и не помнил больше никто.

*например, то, что мы вместе выросли в Хейлшеме, то, что мы знали и помнили такое, чего не знал и не помнил больше никто* - это присоединительная конструкция?

Если да, то по правилу о вводных в начале обособленных оборотов вводные не отделяются запятыми *За оградой мелькнули гипсовые статуи, голубые павильоны, – по всей вероятности городской сад (тире перед присоединительной конструкцией)*. Правда, в другом месте (не на сайте по пунктуации, а в самом произведении: За оградой мелькнули гипсовые статуи, голубые павильоны – по всей вероятности городской сад. Запятой перед тире нет. По-моему, она и не нужна.)

Выходит, надо убрать запятую после *например*?

Answer (score 1):

**Но в конце концов я это устроила, и едва я ее вновь увидела — в центре реабилитации в Дувре, — все, что нас разделяло, не то чтобы исчезло, но стало куда менее важным, чем другое — например, то, что мы вместе выросли в Хейлшеме, то, что мы знали и помнили такое, чего не знал и не помнил больше никто.**

Сложное предложение состоит из нескольких простых, при этом  обособленная часть предложений   **раскрывает содержание** слова ***другое***  с помощью указательных местоимений ТО и отнесенных к ним придаточных.

Это **присоединительная** конструкция , включающая вводное слово ***например*** и имеющая **пояснительное** значение. Правило о вводных словах в начале обособленных оборотов сюда не относится, так здесь присоединительной является сложная конструкция из нескольких предложений.

Комментарий

Вообще говоря, это правило изначально (в редакции 1956 года) **относилось только уточняющим обособленным оборотам, а вводные слова в этом случае играли роль  присоединительных союзов** (меняли свою функцию). Потом это правило стало применяться уже в расширенном варианте, приобрело формальный характер и теперь плохо понимается пользователями. Например, в данном случае мы не можем "соединить" *например* с одним из указательных местоимений, нет в этом никакого смысла. Это вводное слово, а не союз, и оно должно быть обособлено.